# Meteor application doesn't run on Android

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I followed the tutorial in [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html) and also [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile). The application still doesn't run as it should be. I get the following error in the terminal (The application runs on IOS with no errors):

```
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.1, but it should have a minimum version of 2.2.3 to ensure compatibility
         with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for convenience, but you should adjust your dependencies.
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen@4.0.1, but it should have a minimum version of 4.0.3 to ensure
         compatibility with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for convenience, but you should adjust your
         dependencies.

WARNING: It looks like you are using OAuth2 login in your app. Meteor's OAuth2 implementation does not currently work with mobile apps in
         local development mode, except in the iOS simulator. You can run the iOS simulator with 'meteor run ios'. For additional
         workarounds, see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/OAuth-for-mobile-Meteor-clients.

WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile app to be able to connect to the local server, make sure your device
         is on the same network, and that the network configuration allows clients to talk to each other (no client isolation).
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
   Error: Command failed: /Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run --device
   { Error: spawn EACCES
   at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
   at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
   at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
   at exports.spawn
   (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)
   at GradleBuilder.runGradleWrapper
   (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:78:14)
   at /Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:178:21
   at _fulfilled (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
   at self.promiseDispatch.done
   (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
   (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
   at /Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:570:49 code: 'EACCES', errno:
   'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' } 'Error: spawn EACCES\n    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)\n    at ChildProcess.spawn
   (internal/child_process.js:323:11)\n    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)\n    at exports.spawn
   (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)\n
   at GradleBuilder.runGradleWrapper
   (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:78:14)\n    at
   /Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:178:21\n    at _fulfilled
   (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)\n    at
   self.promiseDispatch.done
   (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)\n    at
   Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
   (/Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)\n    at
   /Users/mzn/Desktop/chat/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:570:49'
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23)
   at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
```

What is causing the error?

Any feedback is appreciated

NOTE: I get the same error when trying to run using an emulator.

I can see the emulator running when using `adb devices` in the terminal

Comment: You have some not authorized access to files in the .meteor folder. Maybe you have done some sudo npm install? Try changing the ownership of the files to your username (change username for your username) using this command line: sudo chown -R username /Users/mzn/Desktop/chat

Comment: @bordalix Unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a problem in Android Studio version 3 and Gradle 4.1

Run the following command:

```
sudo chmod 777 /Applications/"Android Studio.app"/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle
```

Then try `meteor run android` and make sure the emulator is running. Use `meteor run android-device` if you want to test it in a real device.